# how to set BUILD_MAC_SDK_EXPERIMENTAL=1 on Mac 10.7?

Tags: android, macos, android-build

I am building Android OS source on Mac 10.7 follow instructions at: http://source.android.com/source/building.html. Below are the error code when I try to run `lunch full-eng`

> BinhNguyens-MacBook:WORKING_DIRECTORY CuongLy$ lunch full-eng
>   2012-10-04 14:02:58.544 xcodebuild[645:80b] XcodeColors: load (v10.1)
>   2012-10-04 14:02:58.560 xcodebuild[645:80b] XcodeColors:
>   pluginDidLoad: build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:62:
>   ***************************************************** build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:63: * Can not find SDK 10.6 at
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
>   build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:65: * If you wish to build using
>   higher version of SDK,  build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:66: * try
>   setting BUILD_MAC_SDK_EXPERIMENTAL=1 before 
>   build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:67: * rerunning this command 
>   build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:69:
>   ***************************************************** build/core/combo/HOST_darwin-x86.mk:70: *** Stop..  Stop.

Please tell me how to set BUILD_MAC_SDK_EXPERIMENTAL=1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type the following:

```
export BUILD_MAC_SDK_EXPERIMENTAL=1
```